# changes elements while scrolling a body

Tags: jquery, media-queries

I just want to changes elements like changing a header while scrolling the body tag just like this site http://www.engadget.com/.

I have tried it but in alerting me that the body is scrolled in a value that I set. So here's the code:

script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("body").scroll( function() {
    var top = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(top > 147){
        alert("hey!");
    }
});

});
```

and the html:

```
<body>
<div style='height: 5000px;' ></div>
</body>
```

any ideas???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach the scroll event to the `document` not the `body`:

```
$(document).scroll( function() {
    var top = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(top > 147){
        alert("hey!");
    }
});
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/grpTU/)

You can relace the `alert()` with the code to amend the DOM as required when the user has scrolled down the page.